# msbuild refuses to copy unsigned dll if it is of lower version than demanded by one of the project dependencies - is it by design?

Tags: msbuild

I have the following situation:

1. All the involved dlls are unsigned
2. All the projects in the solution depend on version 1.0.21221.1 of Shared.dll
3. Some NuGet dependencies of some projects in the solution depend on version 1.0.21237.1 of the same dll.
4. When the web application is built (let us name it **Api**) it is expected to copy Shared.dll from `$(OutDir)` to the `$(OutDir)_PublishedWebsites\Api\bin` folder. The Shared.dll found in `$(OutDir)` has the version 1.0.21221.1.
5. The Shared.dll is NOT copied and the web application fails to run.

Here is the evidence from the binary log:

**Exhibit A - The conflict of versions:**

[image]

**Exhibit B - ResolveAssemblyReference instructs NOT to copy Shared.dll:**

[image]

I understand that msbuild does not like the idea of conflicting versions, but NOT copying the dll produces a downright bug, because the application fails to start.

I understand one can resolve it by adding an assembly binding redirect. But I thought it was unnecessary for unsigned assemblies. Am I understanding wrong or am I missing something?

**EDIT 1**

Here are my answers to the questions posted in the comments:

(Unfortunately I was asked to obfuscate some keywords, I do not know why)

1. **How exactly does the Api project reference Shared.dll?**

As we can see in the **exhibit B** Shared.dll is a transitive dependency of Api. Indeed, Api depends on Xyz.BusinessApi like this:

```
<Reference Include="Xyz.BusinessAPI" />
```

Now that DLL depends on Shared.dll through the respective NuGet dependency, here is a snippet from the project.assets.json file of Xyz.BusinessAPI:
[image]

2. **What other projects reference Shared.dll and how?**

There are a lot of projects referencing it as a NuGet package at version 1.0.21221.1. The problem is that some projects also reference two other NuGet packages which in turn depend on the version 1.0.21237.1 of the same NuGet package. This is indicated in the RAR output - see the **exhibit A**.

I would like to emphasize - no project references Shared.dll as a raw dll, only either as NuGet package or indirectly through other NuGets or projects or **project dlls**. Project dll is a dll of a project from a previously built solution - we do not allow project references to other solutions, so if a project is built in a previous solution, then it would be referenced as DLL in subsequent solutions.

3. **What is the mechanism used to copy from OutDir to _PublishedWebsites\api\bin**?

This is the standard web application publishing target `_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal` from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets:

```
    <!-- copy any referenced assemblies to _PublishedWebsites\app\bin folder -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)"
          DestinationFiles="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
          SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
          Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
          RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"/>
```

4. **How does Shared.dll end up in OutDir?**

All of our code is built into the shared bin directory - we set `OutDir` to the same value for all the projects. Thus all the project binaries and their dependencies, including Shared.dll first end up there.

5. **Are there any double-writes in the binlog?**

Yes, but I do not think they are relevant:
[image]

Comment: Could you please prepare a minimal repro solution/repo with two or three projects, that .dll in question and reproduce it standalone outside of your environment? Then share the source to the repro and I can take a look.

Comment: Several questions need to be answered to understand what's going on:

 1. how exactly does the Api project reference Shared.dll?
 2. what other projects reference Shared.dll and how?
 3. what is the mechanism used to copy from OutDir to _PublishedWebsites\api\bin?
 4. how does Shared.dll end up in OutDir?
 5. are there any double-writes in the binlog?

It might be that all you need is a <Private>true</Private> metadata on the reference.

Comment: If you are going to debug into RAR, here's a good guide: 
https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/main/documentation/wiki/ResolveAssemblyReference.md

Comment: What software are those screenshots from? Looks interesting.

Comment: @stijn - msbuild binary log viewer. You get it by passing /bl flag to msbuild and you analyze them with https://msbuildlog.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that your projects indirectly depend on two versions of Shared.dll: `1.0.21221.1` and  `1.0.21237.1`.

RAR (the MSBuild ResolveAssemblyReference task) inspected all the references of all .dlls and found these two versions. It reported a conflict:

[image: There was a conflict]

Pay attention how it reported the found file path in square brackets for Shared.dll 21221 and reported [] (meaning no file of such version was found) for 21237.

It's useful to search for these using `There was a conflict under($rar)` or `$warning under($rar)`.

Now, the OutDir only contains the Shared.dll 21221, so the Shared.dll with version 21237 couldn't be found anywhere.

The trick is to search for `Shared.dll under($rar project(api.csproj))` You will find the relevant messages from RAR:

[image: 21221 not CopyLocal, 21237 not found]

```
Considered "C:\Xyz\61\bin.link\Shared.dll",
        but its name "Shared, Version=1.0.21221.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
        didn't match the expected name "Shared, Version=1.0.21237.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".
```

So, it saw a conflict, decided to unify on a later version (21237), but didn't find the file of that version. So the reference of 21221 was not CopyLocal because it didn't unify on that version, and the reference to 21237 was not resolved because a file of that version was not found.

To resolve this, I recommend adding an explicit reference to Shared.dll of the version 21237 (either via NuGet or via `GeneratePathProperty` metadata on the package reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#generatepathproperty). If you use GeneratePathProperty you can then reference the .dll directly using `$(PkgFoo_Bar)\lib\net472\Shared.dll` or similar. Also add a binding redirect from 21221 to 21237 to resolve the conflict. Once the correct version (21237) will be in your OutDir, it will get copied to output correctly.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: I realize I can resolve it by either explicitly referencing the higher version OR by eliminating the conflict. What surprises me is that build passes at all. I would have expected it to fail or copy the available version, even if it is lower than requested by one of the dependents **when the dll in question is unsigned**. Would it not be safer, than not copying and not failing?

Comment: Another question - does version unification always prefer the higher version?

Comment: RAR historically doesn't even issue a warning when it hits "Could not resolve this reference". It was historically very lenient because it was unreasonable to expect that everyone provide every single dependency recursively. It never provided any guarantees that all required assemblies from the closure are actually present.

To change this now of course would be a massive breaking change as builds worldwide are in a very random state. This is the sad reality.

Comment: It's debatable what the behavior should be for conflict resolution, but I'm afraid almost any change here would be a breaking change. I guess we're better off providing additional analyzers on top of RAR or binlog that catch these sorts of issues. In an ideal world, RAR wouldn't exist, there's nothing to resolve. Just take whatever comes from NuGet and P2P, that's it. There shouldn't be any guesswork or imperative logic involved. But again, we have what we have.

Comment: I'm not sure about how the conflict resolution and unification works exactly. At this point you're better off reading the RAR source code and debugging it yourself. I wrote an article long back that gives an overview of RAR, it can make it simpler to dive into that code: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/main/documentation/wiki/ResolveAssemblyReference.md

Comment: This is where assembly name conflicts are resolved: https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core/AssemblyDependency/ReferenceTable.cs,4f97c1364a300688

https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/3a1e456fe227f3e2b190b434578844c31e8bcb4a/src/Tasks/AssemblyDependency/ReferenceTable.cs#L2357